# naturalWidth and naturalHeight returns 0 using onload event

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I have read countless of answers of this issue and I came up with the following, but it doesn't work either.

```
function fitToParent(objsParent, tagName) {
    var parent, imgs, imgsCant, a, loadImg;
    //Select images
    parent = document.getElementById(objsParent);
    imgs = parent.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    imgsCant = imgs.length;
    
    function scaleImgs(a) {
        "use strict";
        var w, h, ratioI, wP, hP, ratioP, imgsParent;
        
        //Get image dimensions
        w = imgs[a].naturalWidth;
        h = imgs[a].naturalHeight;
        ratioI = w / h;

        //Get parent dimensions
        imgsParent = imgs[a].parentNode;
        wP = imgsParent.clientWidth;
        hP = imgsParent.clientHeight;
        ratioP = wP / hP;

        //I left this as a test, all this returns 0 and false, and they shouldn't be 
        console.log(w);
        console.log(h);
        console.log(ratioI);
        console.log(imgs[a].complete);

        if (ratioP > ratioI) {
            imgs[a].style.width = "100%";
        } else {
            imgs[a].style.height = "100%";
        }
    }

    //Loop through images and resize them
    var imgCache = [];
    for (a = 0; a < imgsCant; a += 1) {
        imgCache[a] = new Image();
        imgCache[a].onload = function () {
            scaleImgs(a);

            //Another test, this returns empty, for some reason the function fires before aplying a src to imgCache
            console.log(imgCache[a].src);
            
        }(a);
        imgCache[a].src = imgs[a].getAttribute('src');
    }

}
fitToParent("noticias", "img");
```

To summarise, the problem is the event `onload` triggers before the images are loaded (or that is how I understand it).

Another things to add:

- I don't know at first the dimensions of the parent nor the child,
  because they varied depending of their position on the page.
- I don't want to use jQuery.
- I tried with another function, changing the `onload` event to
  `window`, and it worked, but it takes a lot of time to resize because
  it waits for everything to load, making the page appear slower,
  that's how I came to the conclusion the problem has something  to do
  with the `onload` event.

EDIT:

I made a fiddle, easier to look at the problem this way
https://jsfiddle.net/whn5cycf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for some reason the function fires before aplying a src to imgCache

Well, the reason is that *you are* calling the function immedeatly:

```
  imgCache[a].onload = function () {

  }(a);
// ^^^ calls the function
```

You call the function and assign `undefined` (the return value of that function) to `.onload`.

If you want to use an IIFE to capture the current value of `a`, you have to make it return a function and accept a parameter to which the current value of `a` is assigned to:

```
imgCache[a].onload = function (a) {
  return function() {
    scaleImgs(a);
  };
}(a);
```

Have a look again at [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) .

Comment: I modified it and there's still a problem. Give me a minute, I'll do  fiddle of it.

Comment: I assume the problem may be with your `scaleImgs` functions. You probably want to access the element in `imgCache`, not `imgs`. But not really sure.

Comment: I added the fiddle with your changes

Comment: Two issues with your changes: 1) The IIFE still executes immediately, that's its purpose. The `console.log` will still log `undefined` since you are calling it before you set the `src`. You have to move that call inside the inner function. 2) You forgot to add `a` as parameter to the outer function. Please have a look at the link to understand how IIFE's work.

Comment: I got it working, thanks! I still don't fully grasp the concept of closures but I'll keep reading about the subject.